# Bootstrap4 Initializing Toasts

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am working with toasts in Bootstrap 4 and there is one things that's bothering me:

If I initialize the toast

```
<div class="toast my-3" data-delay="2500">
    <div class="toast-header text-dark">
        //fill this later
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body text-dark">
        //fill this later
    </div>
</div>
```

like in the documentation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".toast").toast("show");
});
```

the toast is show as expected, when the page loads. If I don't initialize the toast, the html code takes some place. at the bottom of my page.

How can I make the toast not to be shown when loading the page and not taking some place due to html code? I tried initialize them with toast("hide") or toast("dispose") as well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the html code takes some place"?

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".toast").toast("show");
});
```

It means you're expecting the toast to show as soon as the DOM is loaded. If you want the toast to appear conditionnally, you have for example to create a button in your html file (click on "Run snippet" and click on the button).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toastThis').on( "click", function() {
    $(".toast").toast("show");
  });

});
```

```css
.toast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" id="toastThis" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not put any decent example before. I hope this example clarifies my question: https://jsfiddle.net/p2x1dt4c/

Comment: I updated my snippet. You just have to play with CSS to position your toast.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'll appreciate it. But isn't there any solution for having the default behavior without the spacing other than initializing it on loading the page?